# Hazelcast Multicasting error after stopping the nodes of the cluster

Tags: orientdb, heap-memory, hazelcast, multicast

I am having a cluster of two nodes i.e. two OrientDB servers running on two separate machines having the enterprise edition 2.2.3 .Both the machines are VM having fedora OS 18. The orientDB database consists of approximately 75000 edges and 5000 nodes.

When i try to stop any of the nodes or both the nodes one after other i am having following error:

**Node1**

```
2017-05-02 17:32:44:811 WARNI Received signal: SIGINT [OSignalHandler]Exception in thread "Timer-1" com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.throwNotActiveException(AbstractDistributedObject.java:85)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.lifecycleCheck(AbstractDistributedObject.java:80)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.getNodeEngine(AbstractDistributedObject.java:74)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:309)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:250)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:94)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedMap.get(OHazelcastDistributedMap.java:53)
        at com.orientechnologies.agent.profiler.OEnterpriseProfiler$14.run(OEnterpriseProfiler.java:772)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid11478.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [744789648 bytes in 21.248 secs]
```

**Node2**

```
2017-05-02 17:32:41:108 INFO  [192.168.6.153]:2434 [orientdb] [3.6.3] Running shutdown hook... Current state: ACTIVE [Node]Exception in thread "Timer-1" com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.throwNotActiveException(AbstractDistributedObject.java:85)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.lifecycleCheck(AbstractDistributedObject.java:80)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.getNodeEngine(AbstractDistributedObject.java:74)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:309)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:250)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:94)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedMap.get(OHazelcastDistributedMap.java:53)
        at com.orientechnologies.agent.profiler.OEnterpriseProfiler$14.run(OEnterpriseProfiler.java:772)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

How can i solve the heap memory issue?

[image: Terminal View of both the nodes for reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem is the Out of Memory error. The exception from Hazelcast just means that the HazelcastInstance was stopped, most probably based on the OOME fact.

Comment: I have tried increasing the RAM and configuring the JVM memory but still the same problem persist. Can you suggest some alternatives or possible solutions to solve the Out of Memory error?

Comment: There is no alternative, OOME means you run out of heap. Not sure what the reason is but it means you still don't have enough heap.